# CakePhp - how to access variables inside find->innerJoinWith?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to query for users that are assigned to a certain project in CakePHP. How could I basically achieve this:

```
    $projectId = //Project ID query result.

    $users = $this->Tickets->Users
        ->find('list', ['limit' => 200])
        ->innerJoinWith(
            'ProjectsUsers', function($q){
                return $q->where(['ProjectsUsers.project_id' => $projectId]);
            }
        );
```

This code works when not using variables (eg. replacing $projectId with 8) but when I try to use variables I get: `Undefined variable: projectId`

How can I pass variables into innerJoinWith?

Comment: Do you actually have this line in your code?  $projectId = //Project ID query result. That is not how to initialize a variable.

Comment: Ofc not, it's just an abstraction for that query since it works and is not relevant to the questin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean how to inherit a variable from the parent scope, you'd do it like this.

```
 $users = $this->Tickets->Users
        ->find('list', ['limit' => 200])
        ->innerJoinWith(
            'ProjectsUsers', function($q) use($variableToPass) {
                return $q->where(['ProjectsUsers.project_id' => $variableToPass]);
            }
        );
```

Comment: yeah that was it, thanks!